# How to make a hollow square in python?

Tags: python, algorithm, loops

By Using Loop, Print

---

- ```
      *
  ```
- ```
      *
  ```
- ```
      *
  ```
- ```
      *
  ```

---

Print hollow square by using loops in python.

Comment: "Homework must be done on your own. If you have a question about homework, don't ask him to do it for you. Ask a specific question about a problem you cannot solve. Programming is something that you need to understand yourself, or not do it at all. If programming is an extra subject in your curriculum for you, there are sites and people on these sites who complete tasks for material rewards. Here, offering to do the work for you and vice versa is bad manners."

Comment: I have tried this question lot of time but I didn't get it, therefore I asked here. I will keep your advice in mind.

Answer (score 0):

You may use below function to generate hollow square of side length "side"

```
def hollow_square(side):
    for i in range(side):
        for j in range(side):
            if i == 0 or i == side-1 or j == 0 or j == side-1:
                print("*", end="")
            else:
                print(" ", end="")
        print()

 hollow_square(5)
```

Answer (score 0):

you could do it in this way

```
n = int(input("enter the number:"))

def spaces(n):    # creating spaces 
    sp = ""
    for i in range(n-2):
    sp += " "

    return sp

for i in range(n):

    if(i == 0) :          # for top row 
        print('*'*n)
    
    elif (i==n-1) :       #for bottom row
        print('*'*n)

    else :                # for the middle section 
        print(f"*{spaces(n)}*")
```